# Cannot resolve symbol runfx.args in commandlineArgs in configuration POM.xml file

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx-8, maven-3

When i create a maven project in IntelliJ there is a problem with the POM.xml file.The file is as follows.

[image]
It is showing runfx.args cannot resolve symbol.

Can any body resolve this problem.

Comment: is runfx.args defined in the pom.xml?

Comment: what could be the solution?

Comment: Are you creating this as a new project from scratch in IDEA or is this an existing project that you opened in IDEA? The runfx.args is something used by Netbeans. It's defined in a file named nbactions.xml. If this is the case, you are dealing with a non-portable project so you could either switch to Netbeans or try to update the pom.xml to avoid using runfx.args.